# AttributeError: 'KerasTPUModel' object has no attribute '_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu

I am training a model with the following settings:

- Keras model
- TPU
- Google Colab
- Tensorflow 1.12
- Python3.6

Here is my train code:

```
tpu_model.fit(
    dataset.make_one_shot_iterator(),
    epochs=2,
    steps_per_epoch=100
)
```

And my dataset is a simple **tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))**.

And I get this strange error:

> AttributeError: 'KerasTPUModel' object has no attribute '_distribution_strategy'

Thank.

Julien

Comment: try to look in the code that model was properly compiled. I faced the same problem but fixed it, look in the code of compilation **tpu_model.compile**

Comment: Ok thank you. I did not know that it was possible to dive into the compiled code. I only approached Tensorflow from the abstract point of view without really learning about the graph and everything.
I will check this.